# Injecting a service into an entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have an entity called `Container` which depends on a service, `DeviceService`.

I currently inject it using an *Entity Listener* on *postLoad*. However this is not being injected when just creating the plain object `new Container()`.

Should I create a `ContainerFactory` where I inject the service into the new object, along with the current listener, or do a smarter way exist in Symfony?

Comment: It's pretty bad practice to inject a service into an entity (especially when just creating a new instance and not using it for any events like postLoad). Can you explain a bit more what's the background and why you would need a Service with your Entity?

Comment: It's not a best practice to inject services into an entity. I'd review the design and try to figure out if that dependency is only for a single method on the entity. If it is, you might be able to pass that dependency when calling that method instead.

Comment: Sometimes it does make sense to give an entity access to a service.  So yes, a ContainerFactory is what you need for creating a new object.  Sometime I cheat and just add a create method to the Doctrine repository class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony 2.0 getting service inside entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330704/symfony-2-0-getting-service-inside-entity)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Doctrine events. See : https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform-extending/post-load-listener