# Custom Extension - CurrentUserExtension, Symfony error

Tags: api-platform.com

I would like to create a Custom Extension in my API, created thanks to [api-platform](https://api-platform.com/). I tried to follow the [documentation about extensions](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extensions) to do exactly the same thing : get data owned by the current user. But I've the following error :

> (1/1) FatalThrowableError
>   Type error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Doctrine\ORM\Extension\CurrentUserExtension::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface, none given, called in /var/www/api/var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 579

I tried to remove cache files, but I've the same issue.

My configuration :
symfony/symfony v3.3.10 
api-platform/schema-generator : v1.2.0

api_filters.yml :

```
services:
    ...
    'AppBundle\Doctrine\ORM\Extension\CurrentUserExtension':
        tags:
            - { name: api_platform.doctrine.orm.query_extension.collection, priority: 9 }
            - { name: api_platform.doctrine.orm.query_extension.item }
```

CurrentUserExtension.php :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Doctrine\ORM\Extension;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Extension\QueryCollectionExtensionInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Extension\QueryItemExtensionInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Util\QueryNameGeneratorInterface;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use AppBundle\Entity\Voyage;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker;

final class CurrentUserExtension implements QueryCollectionExtensionInterface, QueryItemExtensionInterface
{
    private $tokenStorage;
    private $authorizationChecker;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage, AuthorizationChecker $checker)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->authorizationChecker = $checker;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function applyToCollection(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator, string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null)
    {
        $this->addWhere($queryBuilder, $resourceClass);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function applyToItem(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator, string $resourceClass, array $identifiers, string $operationName = null, array $context = [])
    {
        $this->addWhere($queryBuilder, $resourceClass);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param QueryBuilder $queryBuilder
     * @param string       $resourceClass
     */
    private function addWhere(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, string $resourceClass)
    {
        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
        if ($user instanceof User && Voyage::class === $resourceClass && !$this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
            $rootAlias = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases()[0];
            $queryBuilder->andWhere(sprintf('%s.user = :current_user', $rootAlias));
            $queryBuilder->setParameter('current_user', $user->getId());
        }
    }
}
```

config.yml :

```
[...]
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address:        "%mailer_user%"
        sender_name:    Guilhem

api_platform:
    title:           API - Le Monde en Sac
    description:     The core API for the website Le Monde en Sac
    enable_fos_user: true
    http_cache:
        invalidation:
            enabled: false
            varnish_urls: []
    eager_loading:
        max_joins: 1
```

Do you have any idea where is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved :

service.yml :

```
services:
    'AppBundle\Doctrine\ORM\Extension\CurrentUserExtension':
        arguments:
            - '@security.token_storage'
            - '@security.authorization_checker'
        tags:
            - { name: api_platform.doctrine.orm.query_extension.collection, priority: 9 }
            - { name: api_platform.doctrine.orm.query_extension.item }
```

Comment: mind, letting me know how to got it to initiate the service? I've done all the above but I'm unsure how to reference it in my entity?

Comment: @Doug be sure to look at **both** answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330704/symfony-2-0-getting-service-inside-entity